# saving select result into variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having some problem with this statement

```
declare @result int

select @result =   (select 1 union select 2)

select @result
```

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

plz help T_T

Comment: You are trying to save 2 values into an `int` variable that can only take 1 value. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Mysql or sql server which is it?

Comment: i'm trying to save a subquery to a variable... how do i save multiple value to a variable?

Comment: You can't to a scalar variable. You can insert to a table variable but why are you trying to do this? What are you planning on doing with it afterwards? You might just need a CTE.

Comment: i'm trying to use the subquery to check for diferent data over and over again, so i thought that if i saved the subquery result the query would run faster because the subquery wont be run over and over again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` can only store one value, not two.  Consider using an array of integers:

```
declare @arr table (result int)
insert @arr (result) select 1 union select 2
```

Comment: Should work, [live example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f95b/1).  Is your database compatibility set to an old version?

Comment: to select >> select * from @arr